# Why setInterval() inside Observable.create() keeps on running?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rxjs

I'm studying rxjs Observables and I couldn't understand why the setInterval inside Observable.create is still running even I have unsubscribe to that observable object. Observable is async right? When it supposed to stop?

I have this code for reference:

```
var cancellableObserver = Observable.create((observer:any)=>{
try {
    observer.next("anyeong")
    observer.next("ande")
    console.log("logged once")
    setInterval(()=>{
        //this code block will keep running for every 2secs
        observer.next("eotteokke") //but this line will stop after unsubscribe
        console.log("will log every 2secs")
    },2000)
} catch (err) {
    observer.error(err);

}});

var cancellableSubscription = cancellableObserver.subscribe(
(x:any) =>addItem(x),
(err:any) =>addItem(err),
() => addItem("cancellable completed"));

setTimeout(() => {cancellableSubscription.unsubscribe();console.log("mary");}, 6001);
```

Comment: get the interval process_id et use method clearInterval, setInterval works independently

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setInterval` is scheduled by JavaScript's runtime. When you unsubscribe from an Observable that called `setInterval` no-one tells the runtime to cancel the scheduled action. You might actually want to keep the interval running in some use-cases.

So instead you have to call `clearInterval` yourself on unsubscription that you return from the `Observable`'s callback:

```
const source$ = new Observable(observer => {
  const handler = setInterval(...);

  ...

  return () => clearInterval(handler);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval` is not dependent on your observable, it will continue running until you clear it by using the `clearInterval()` function. To clear the interval, you have to use the returned `intervalID` (which is returned from `setInterval()`).

**Examples:**

```
// Assigning an intervalID to a variable
const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
 // Do some stuff here...
}, 2000);
```

```
// Clearing an interval
clearInterval(intervalID);
```

**[Source and further information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)**

Comment: You're correct that what needs to happen here is clearing the interval using the intervalID returned by setInterval. However, claiming that this has anything to do with the scope of setInterval is a bit of a red herring. :)

Comment: @korona You're right. I think the wording I chose is not quite correct, I did not mean the scope as  JavaScript scope. More like that the setInterval is not depending/relying on the observer itself (is not being handled by it).